# Multiple Forms, Deligation e.preventdefault Issue not working on live server.

Tags: javascript, events, gruntjs

I have a very strange problem I cant seem to make sense of.

Here is the story...
I created a product page which when visited performs an ajax request to a json file to obtain product data, I then have a js script while dynamically appends html to create my checkout forms for each product.

Therefore, there are multiple dynamically created forms on one page.

My issue is this....

Everything works on my local server as when a form is submitted, 'e.preventdefault' stops any submission of forms with no selected items.

As soon as I build with grunt and pass to live server, e.preventdefault does not seem to work and forms are submitted....

Its been 3 hours now and I cant seem to figure our where I am going wrong.

```
$(".initial-cont").on("submit", ".payment-form", function(e){

var size2 = $(this).find(".size").val();
var style2 = $(this).find(".style").val();
var postage2 = $(this).find(".postage").val();

if ( (size2 == 777) || (size2 == null) ) {

  BootstrapDialog.alert({
    title: 'Error',
    message: 'Please select artwork size.',
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING
});
```

`    e.preventDefault();
    return;
    }

//more validation similar to above

Notes: 
.initial container already exists on page. (Not dynamic)
.payment-form is class name of form

Thanks is advance.

Ryan

Comment: Solved Guys - Thanks anyway

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, ensure 'e.preventDefault' is the first line of code after your event, as its possible it will not trigger and continue to submit the form. 

So the solution is prevent default submition of form by adding 'e.preventDefault' at the beginning of your script. Then manually call the submit when validation has passed. (JQuery's .submit() function worked well.)